# Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

> I Keep my model class in the com.anand.model.Employee.java and
>   correctly I mentioned in the sdnext-servlet.xml for annotatedClasses.
>   But still I am getting the error. Please help me to solve this issue.

sdnext-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.anand.model.Employee</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>             
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Model Class : Employee.java

```
package com.anand.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * @author Anand Gopalan
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="Employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -723583058586873479L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "empid")
    private Integer empId;

    @Column(name="empname")
    private String empName;

    @Column(name="empaddress")
    private String empAddress;

    @Column(name="salary")
    private Long salary;

    @Column(name="empAge")
    private Integer empAge;

    public Integer getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(Integer empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    public String getEmpAddress() {
        return empAddress;
    }

    public void setEmpAddress(String empAddress) {
        this.empAddress = empAddress;
    }

    public Long getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(Long salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public Integer getEmpAge() {
        return empAge;
    }

    public void setEmpAge(Integer empAge) {
        this.empAge = empAge;
    }

}
```

Logs:

> SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
>   **org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/config/sdnext-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert
>   property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type
>   'java.lang.Class[]' for property 'annotatedClasses'; nested exception
>   is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class
>   [com.anand.model.Employee]**  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:545)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:443)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5229)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5516)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert
>   property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type
>   'java.lang.Class[]' for property 'annotatedClasses'; nested exception
>   is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class
>   [com.anand.model.Employee]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:457)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1313)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
>     ... 26 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot
>   find class [com.anand.model.Employee]     at
>   org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:294)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.ClassEditor.setAsText(ClassEditor.java:64)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:474)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:446)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:215)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:122)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedArray(TypeConverterDelegate.java:485)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:227)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:154)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:452)
>     ... 30 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.anand.model.Employee  at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
>     at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:291)
>     ... 39 more
>
> Oct 14, 2014 11:40:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   loadOnStartup SEVERE: Servlet /sdnext threw load() exception
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.anand.model.Employee    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
>     at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:291)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.ClassEditor.setAsText(ClassEditor.java:64)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:474)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:446)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:215)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:122)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedArray(TypeConverterDelegate.java:485)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:227)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:154)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:452)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1313)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:545)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:443)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5229)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5516)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: You should clear and rebuild

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an alternative to what you have done. Try to replace the `annotatedClasses` with that of the following element in your config and clean build your workspace after that + restart your server .

```
<property name="packagesToScan">
    <list>
        <value>com.anand.model</value>           
    </list>
</property>
```

Comment: Why replacing annotatedClasses with packagesToScan works? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: but this code is not working please give another solution.

Answer (score 0):

a solution for your question: clean the maven and update the maven once again, and build it. It will work, maven is missing some packages for that reason it shows that error, so once clean and update maven

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean Maven files and Build it and clean the project and also clean Server work directory and clean server. and Run the project. It will work.

Comment: The expected command sequence would help, with descriptions of what each one does. A little more of a walk-through approach.