# Failed to convert property value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.lang.Class[] ] for property 'annotatedClasses'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, configuration

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adminPanelController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'blog_statusDAO'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Blog_statusDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.lang.Class[]' for property 'annotatedClasses'; nested exception is
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [com.journaldev.spring.model.Connection]
```

That is my log error, and I use the following code in my spring configuration:

```
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Blog_status</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Car</beans:value>
                 <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Connection</beans:value>
             <!--     <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Tool</beans:value> 
 -->        </beans:list>
        </beans:property> 
    </beans:bean>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367159/initialization-of-bean-failed-nested-exception-is-org-springframework-beans

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367159/initialization-of-bean-failed-nested-exception-is-org-springframework-beans)

Comment: i tried , but it displays same error . When i delete connection and tool class , it works perfectly